# What is the best practices for getting code into a docker container?

Tags: docker

What is the best practices for getting code into a docker container?

Here are some possible approaches:

- ADD call in docker container
- git clone or git wget from repo in docker container
- Mount an external device

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, we use `mount` for dev/local environment with docker to have the code changes instantly applied.

You can use `RUN git clone` but you will need to install git and have access to the repository.

The easiest and most used/recommended way is putting the Dockerfile inside your repo and use the `ADD` call. But use the `COPY` directive instead because it’s more explicit

Comment: Are you using -v or --mount?

Comment: Could you please provide more information how you put the Dockerfile inside your repo and use the ADD call?

Comment: Commit your **Dockerfile** with your project repository at the base level (where usually you put your README.md and .gitignore). If you want only to copy files I use the **COPY** directive instead because it’s more explicit `COPY . .`

Comment: @sys0dm1n and when Dockerfile is inside the repo, how do you manage files that are copied, for instance an apache myapache.conf file that contains virtualhost configuration. Do you place it in the repo ?

Comment: @Nico Adding Virtualhost and other configuration to the docker image should be done separately. Here you only call the pre-built image (from your private registry) with your custom configuration and copy the code before using it.

Comment: @sys0dm1n ok your comment is interesting, if I understand well thus the pre-built image is from another Dockerfile which has maybe some configuration files (apache, ...), ... the pre-built image is pushed in a private registry... and this Dockerfile and conf files that has been used to create the pre-built image are in another git repository ?

Comment: @Nico Yes, I hope it helps. Good luck

Answer (score 5):

You should always `COPY` your application code in the Dockerfile.  You generally shouldn't mount something over that, and you almost definitely shouldn't run `git` in your Dockerfile.

Running Git has a number of obvious issues.  You can only build whatever specific commit the Dockerfile mentions; in real development it's not unusual to want to build a branch or a past commit.  You need to install both `git` itself and relevant credentials in the image, with corresponding space and security issues.  Docker layer caching means that `docker build` by default won't repeat a `git clone` step if it thinks it's already done that, which means you need to go out of your way to get a newer build.

It's very common in SO questions to mount code into a container.  This very much defeats the point of Docker, IMHO.  If you go to run your application in production you want to just distribute the image and not also separately distribute its code, but if you've been developing in an environment where you always hide the code built into the image, you've never actually run the image itself.  There are also persistent performance and consistency problems in various environments.  I don't really recommend `docker run -v` or Docker Compose `volumes:` as a way of getting code into a container.

I've seen enough SO questions that have a Dockerfile that's essentially just `FROM python`, for example, and then use Docker Compose `volumes:` and `command:` options to get a live-development environment on top of that.  It's much easier to just install Python, and have the tools you need right in front of you without needing to go through a complex indirection sequence to run them in Docker.